# Workbox BackgroundSyncPlugin _ Failed Request _ Notifications

Tags: http-headers, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, backgroundworker, workbox

i have a pwa who works fine. I make it with workbox.
But i want to try something.
I want to push notification when : the request ( who was hold in IndexeDB -> thanks of BackgroundSyncPlugin ) have an error ( like Error 500 ). The request send, is not the probleme of BackgroundSyncPlugin, but a probleme with my HTTP request. And i want to warn user that the request wasn't work

here a part of my service worker :

```js
const bgSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('myQueueName', {
    maxRetentionTime: 0.1 * 60, // mins,
    onSync: async({ queue }) => {
        let entry;
        while ((entry = await queue.shiftRequest())) {
            try {
                await fetch(entry.request);
                console.error("Replay successful for request", entry.request);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Replay failed for request", entry.request, error);

                // Put the entry back in the queue and re-throw the error:
                await queue.unshiftRequest(entry);
                throw error;
            }
        }
        console.log("Replay complete!");
        showNotification();
    }
});


registerRoute(
    /http:\/\/localhost:8000/,
    new NetworkFirst({
        plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```

I just want to know the status code of my request
Any help :)

Edit : i want to get [Body in header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVJp.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXKkE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change this line:

```js
await fetch(entry.request);
```

to

```js
const response = await fetch(entry.request);
// Check response.status, and do something, e.g. throw an
// Error when it's above 500:
if (response.status > 500) {
  // Throwing an Error will trigger a retry.
  throw new Error('Status: ' + response.status);
}

// This assumes that your response from the server is JSON,
// and has an error field which might be set if the request
// failed for some reason, regardless of the HTTP status code.
const responseJSON = await response.json();
if (responseJSON.error) {
  throw new Error('Failed request: ' + responseJSON.error);
}
```

Comment: Do you think, that i can see if my request make an exception ? I wish that, if for example, I have a form and that the creation of an item is not done. An exception is raised and I want to inform the user. Without necessarily generating an error 500. When i am on line a message display. But when i am offline, the message can't display (even after we are online back )

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're describing here.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try to explain myself better. When a request is sent but it does not work. For example a request to add an article to the database, the request is sent well but for x reasons the article is not add to the database. So I don’t have an error 500 but the return of my request is an error message.
But when the user is offline and then online again, the message for this e=type of error does not display.
How to notify the user that the item does not know sent
I’m trying to be clear

Comment: Well, that depends on what your server responds with, but the basic idea would be to check the body of the response and take appropriate action. I've updated the sample code to reflect that.

Comment: thanks, but i dont' have any message json in my request.

Comment: The code is parsing the response from the server. You can adapt it to deal with whatever the response body looks like when there's an error.

Comment: ok i understand, thanks you. Just to finich can you please help me to get Body in response header  ( i put the picture of what i want in the question :) )

Comment: `const bodyHeader = response.headers.get('body')`